# Data Factory - Run data Load from Point of Failure

Tags: sql-server, salesforce, azure-data-factory, data-migration

I am migrating data from SQL Server On Premise to Salesforce using Azure Data Factory Copy Activity.

We have few tables with Billions of Records at source side (SQL Server). I have requirement to run the Pipeline from last failed stage while loading data.

Example: if the Copy activity fails after copying 12000 records, is it possible to re-run/restart the pipeline such that the Copy activity avoids copying already copied records (1200 records which were copied in earlier run) and resume copy operation from remaining records.

Comment: if you had a sql sink instead of salesforce, you could use `Pre-copy script` proprty to mention a custom script to identify already existing columns and copy only the rest. But your scenario has Salesforce as sink

Comment: was my updated answer helpful ?

Comment: If the answer was helpful , You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 0):

### --Update

You can leverage Azure CLI or PowerShell to manually invoke and rerun the pipeline from the failed activity point.

Please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71124839/15969417) using PowerShell.

Further, checkout usage of flags `--is-recovery` and `--start-from-failure` in

1. Powershell: [Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline (Az.DataFactory) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/invoke-azdatafactoryv2pipeline?view=azps-7.2.0#syntax)) and
2. AzureCLI: [az datafactory pipeline create-run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/datafactory/pipeline?view=azure-cli-latest#az-datafactory-pipeline-create-run)

---

You can use one of the ADF pipeline templates, [View documentation](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2059735)

Use this template to copy new or updated rows only from database using high-watermark stored in an external control table.

> [image]