# Re-Run ADF activity from the point of failure using Azure CLI

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-cli

Is there a way to execute re-run from failed activity in ADF using Azure CLI?? I read the documetation and only found a way to re-run the trigger

```
az datafactory trigger-run rerun --factory-name "exampleFactoryName" --resource-group "exampleResourceGroup" --run-id "2f7fdb90-5df1-4b8e-ac2f-064cfa58202b" --trigger-name "exampleTrigger"
```

Is there a way I can do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the following command

```
az datafactory pipeline create-run --factory-name "factoryName" --name "pipelineName" --resource-group "resourceGroup" --is-recovery "true" --reference-pipeline-run-id "failed-run-id" --start-from-failure "true"
```

Comment: Only allows me to accept my answer after two days.

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell ...

Run `Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline` with `-StartFromFailure` flag to Start rerun from failed activities.

Example:

```
Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline
      -ResourceGroupName "RGname"
      -DataFactoryName "ADFname"
      -PipelineName "PipeleineName"
      -ReferencePipelineRunId "RunID"
      -IsRecovery
      -StartFromFailure
```