# How to rerun an Azure Data Factory without using triggers?

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, pipeline

I am a Software Engineering Associate and I am pretty new using Microsoft Azure. The client wants me to create a re-run function for the whole pipeline without using triggers. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just updating my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71124086/re-run-adf-activity-from-the-point-of-failure-using-azure-cli), maybe you can use that too.

You can leverage a [**PowerShell function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-powershell) to invoke and rerun the pipeline.

[Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline (Az.DataFactory) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/invoke-azdatafactoryv2pipeline?view=azps-7.2.0#syntax))

> [image: Further, checkout usage of flags --is-recovery and --start-from-failure in]

Further, checkout usage of flags `--is-recovery` and `--start-from-failure` to rerun from a failed point without triggers.

Comment: Will see if the PowerShell is okay to use while using another function